# Chaining parameters without parentheses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence, currying

I'm trying to write a convenience wrapper for [`hnetcdf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hnetcdf) library. Instead of dealing with its low-level interface, I want to be able to describe NetCDF file structure in a simple declarative manner. To achieve this I've created a bunch of ADTs:

```
data Info = Info FileInfo Dimentions Variables
data FileInfo   = FileInfo String Int
data Dimentions = Dimentions [Dimention]
data Variables  = Variables [Variable]
data Dimention  = BoundedDimention String Int | UnboundedDimention String
data Variable   = Variable String Int NC.NcType [Dimention]
```

They work if I use them like in the following example:

```
writeNetCDF :: FilePath -> IO ()
writeNetCDF filename = do
    let dimX, dimY, dimZ = ...
    let var1, var2       = ...
    let info = Info (FileInfo filename 1)
                    (Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ])
                    (Variables  [var1, var2])
    ...
```

but I really dislike extra parenthesis. I tried to use `($)` and `(.)`, but with no luck:

```
    -- No way.
    let info = Info $ FileInfo filename 1
                    $ Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ]
                    $ Variables  [var1, var2]
```

Is there another way to chain curried parameters?

Comment: For information, `$` is right-associative. `Info $ FileInfo filename 1 $ Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ] $ Variables  [var1, var2]` is equivalent to `Info (FileInfo filename 1 (Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ] ( Variables  [var1, var2])))`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. The problem of `$` in this case is that it's right associative:

```
let info = Info $ FileInfo filename 1
                $ Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ]
                $ Variables  [var1, var2]
         = Info ( FileInfo filename 1
                  ( Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ]
                    ( Variables  [var1, var2])
                  )
                )
```

So all you need is an operator that's left associative:

```
($<) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($<) = ($)

infixl 0 $< -- left associative
```

Now the parentheses are correct:

```
let info = Info $< FileInfo filename 1
                $< Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ]
                $< Variables  [var1, var2]
         = (
            (
             (Info 
               (FileInfo filename 1)
             )
             (Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ])
            )
            (Variables  [var1, var2])
           )
```

Comment: Is such a left-associative operator defined anywhere in the standard library?

Comment: @Jubobs: [Doesn't seem like it](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20b).

Comment: @Jubobs: I didn't manage to find it too. But if it is, it probably should be named `€` or `¥`.

Comment: @firegurafiku: Huh. Didn't think of that. Might be hard on US keyboards, though. But that's just my 2 ¢.

Answer (score 0):

Both `let` and `where` clauses are calculated recursively so you could have something like:

```
where
    info = Info f dim vars
    f = FileInfo filename 1
    dim = Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ]
    vars = Variables [var1, var2]
```

The `$` operator and the `.` operator are used to create a new function.  Thus the expression below:

```
info = Info $ FileInfo filename 1
            $ Dimentions [dimX, dimY, dimZ]
            $ Variables  [var1, var2]
```

says that Info is a Type Constructor that takes *one* argument, a type that is returned by the FileInfo type which is expected to take three agruments (`filename`, `1` and whatever is returned by this next function called `Dimentions`) and so on.  This isn't at all what you want.

The `.` operator joins two functions together in the mathematics way of `(f . g)(x)` is equivalent to `f(g(x))`.  And again, this is in no way similar to what you are trying to create here.